# i install zabbix 6.4 on ubuntu 22.04.5

Tags: package-management

```
zabbix-agent : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
                Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4) but it is not installable
                Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
 zabbix-server-mysql : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
                       Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libodbc2 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libopenipmi0 (>= 2.0.29) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsnmp40 (>= 5.9.1+dfsg) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
                       Recommends: snmpd but it is not going to be installed
```

How to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)